# Deep learn CNN - super resolution

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am junior at deep learning and CNN and I ran into that article - https://blog.floydhub.com/colorizing-b&w-photos-with-neural-networks/.

I started with the Alpha version (as I said I am a noob) and successfully colored a picture (that I trained the model on before... but it still counts for me :)).

Anyway I am trying to enlarge the image (super resolution not resize) via the CNN model without great success - I have some troubles with the color space (as I manage to understand) and maybe the dimensions.
Also as you can guess the logic is slightly different (comparing the basic image to bigger image).

I uploaded my code (with the test images) - if you try to run this model as is you can see that the picture at the end "img_gray_version.png" (after the model is trained) doesn't look good (and the model actually colorize and train according to that image).

```
image = img_to_array(load_img('1.png'))
Yimage = img_to_array(load_img('1y.png'))
image = np.array(image, dtype=float)
Yimage = np.array(Yimage, dtype=float)

X = rgb2lab(1.0/255*image)[:,:,0]
Y = rgb2lab(1.0/255*Yimage)[:,:,1:]
Y /= 128
X = X.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(1, 96, 96, 2)

# Building the neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(None, None, 1)))
model.add(UpSampling2D((3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (6, 6), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')

model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size=1, epochs=2500)

print(model.evaluate(X, Y, batch_size=1))
output = model.predict(X)
output *= 128
Y *= 128

# Output colorizations
cur = np.zeros((96, 96, 3))
cur[:,:,0] = Y[0][:,:,0]
cur[:,:,1:] = output[0]
imsave("img_result.png", lab2rgb(cur))
imsave("img_gray_version.png", rgb2gray(lab2rgb(cur)))
```

[X - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaJco.jpg)
[Y - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxGlM.jpg)

Image results:
[img_gray_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYDGi.png)
[img_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KeO0.png)
I really need your help on this one guys!
Thanks for the help

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the full code.

Comment: Edited + the missing lines.

Comment: I am familiar with another method for [super resolution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08155) which gave me great results. If im not mistaken, you are trying to colorize and scale up the image in the same network. I do not know enough to say if this is a valid approach but if your model doesn't provide good results even with a decent sized train set, perhaps you could try two networks or the technique mentioned in the paper. Let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: Can you also provide a link to output "img_gray_version.png"  you mentioned that didn't look good..?

Comment: Hey,

Thank you for the help first of all, as far as I know this approach should be ok, I am trying to do this that way because I dont want to learn another network but if there is no other option that what I will do.

I added the 2 result images to the original comment